# CULTUREINFO in microsoft speech recognition

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

im have a little problem, with cultureinfo, my peace of code :

```
using (SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR")))
```

the program compile fine, but not detect any word, and no errors displayed.
if i change to en-US, the program works fine.

i already downloaded - the language pack from MS website. already rebooted my machine

what im missing?

thanks in advance